# Extrair e incluir dados SQL com R

Tags: mysql, sql, r

Estou projetando uma base de dados em SQL que terá tabelas que armazenam dados coletados e um tabela que armazena índices calculados desses dados para posteriormente serem expostos em uma dashboard. Pretendo calcular esses índices com a linguagem R. Gostaria de saber duas coisas:
1 - Como faço para puxar os dados das minhas tabelas de dados em SQL para o R para poder efetuar os cálculos?
2 - Como eu faço para armazenar os resultados dos meus cálculos no R na minha tabela SQL de índices?

Comment: Olha aqui: https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL

Comment: qual sistema de banco de dados está usando? precisa saber se existe o driver para o sistema que está usando. Se existir o driver, é só olhar na documentação como fazer updates com ele, ou reescrever tabelas com ele. 

O pessoal do dplyr fez um backend onde poderia se fazer manipulações com o próprio dplyr, usando um banco de dados por trás. Talvez seja legal dar uma olhada. Mas depende do seu sistema e da existencia de  um driver.

Comment: No linux estou testando no MySql e no Windows estou usando o SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Cara vc usa do pacote `RODBC`, depois é só fazer a consulta:

```
#testa se vc tem o pacote, caso não instala    
list.of.packages <- c("RODBC") 
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)   

library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=mysqlhost;database=mydbname;trusted_connection=true')
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from information_schema.tables')
```

Comment: Só para complementar, caso esteja usando outro SGBD que não seja o SQL Server do exemplo acima, será preciso pesquisar as strings de conexão, pois cada SGBD tem suas particularidades nas conexões. O melhor site para isso é o `www.connectionstrings.com`.